# Use structures values and all in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm new to C and programming in general so I don't know a lot of vocabulary (sorry if you don't understand my question...)

```
#define define1 "\x1F\C0\x00\xF1"
#define define2 "\x3F\xD0\x01\xF1"

struct my_struct {
  char one[5], two[5];
};

struct my_struct list[] = {
    {define1, define2},
}

// the ? is supposed to be define1 from list[] but I don't know how to write it
print("%s", ?);
if (? == 3) {..}
```

my problem here is to use `define1` (`?` currently) in the print statement and in the condition.

it would save me a lot of time if someone understand this !

Thanks.

Comment: And you need to tell us what you are actually trying to do. Putting in code that obviously doesn't work and is incomplete isn't a helpful way to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Since you have an embedded null and non-printable characters in `define1` and everywhere you assign its value, you should not pass it as a format specifier for `%s` in a format string.

As for your comparison, what are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access one and two members of list array by indexing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define define1 "str1"
#define define2 "str2"

struct my_struct {
  char one[5], two[5];
};

struct my_struct list[] = {
    {define1, define2},
};

int main(){
    printf("%s", list[0].one);
}
```

OUTPUT:
`str1`

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/uP0l6YWC3C

Comment: thank you! a last question: if I add `{define3, define4},`, how do I take every `one` value from the list ?

Comment: I meant something like this : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/XT7elQbWec

Comment: What do you want to check with `if (3 == list[<all>].before) ` ?

Comment: if every `before` of the list are equals to 3

Comment: Then you have to make a counter variable and check that in loop for each index